# WiFiClientSecure setCaCert does not accept my parameters

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, iot, esp32, aws-iot-core

I am currently trying to connect my ESP32 to AWS IoT. Therefore, I have to use certificates to encrypt the connection. In theory I know how this will work, but I´m not a C++ pro and I get an error. Of course I tried to google, but I always find the same solution which does not work for me. To be concrete, I try ti declare a cacert in a header file like so:

```
const char AWS_CERT_CA[] = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"MIIDQTChkiG9w0CAimfz5m/jAo5gAwIBBgkqBAkPmljZbyjQsAgITBmy4vB4iANF\n" \
"ADA5MGQW1hem5sGQW1hemDVVUzEMQxBBDVhMQsYDVQQQGEwJQDExBBbWF6\n" \
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
```

In the main file I try to use it like so:

```
WiFiClientSecure net = WiFiClientSecure();
void connectToAWS()
{
    // Configure WiFiClientSecure to use the AWS certificates we generated
    net.setCACert(AWS_CERT_CA);
    net.setCertificate(AWS_CERT_CRT);
    net.setPrivateKey(AWS_CERT_PRIVATE);
...
```

When I try to compile, it gives me the following error:

[image]

Obviously, the parameter types are not correct, but why does it work for others (e.g. [here](https://awsm.dvlprz.com/2017-10-16-esp32-aws-iot-mqtt) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-an-aws-iot-core-device-using-aws-serverless-and-an-esp32/))? An int as a parameter for the function does not make sense to me. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it took me quite w while to figure out how I can solve this. The main problem was that I am using an old version of BearSSL, but I was not able to update it. To circumvent this problem, I create files out of my cryptographic information and use these files for creating the secured connection to AWS iot. Furthermore, I do not use MQTT to transfer my metrics, but the REST endpoint. I am sure this is not an optimal solution, but it works so far. Here´s how I´ve done it.
Things to understand first:

- net is an instance of WiFiClientSecure: BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure net = BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure();

My cryptographic information (key, CACert, cert) looks like this:

```
const char AWS_CA_CERT[]="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
...
"rqXRfboQnoZsG4q5WTP468SQvvG5\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
```

After establishing the Wifi connection, I do the following to establish the secure connection:

```
bool establishSecureConnection()
{
  if (!SPIFFS.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
    return false;
  }

  File tempCA = SPIFFS.open("/ca.crt", "w");
  File tempCert = SPIFFS.open("/cert.crt", "w");
  File tempKey = SPIFFS.open("/cert.priv", "w");

  if (!tempCA || !tempCert || !tempKey)
  {
    Serial.println("There was an error opening the file for writing");
    return false;
  }

  if (tempCA.print(AWS_CA_CERT))
  {
    Serial.println("Ca File was written");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Ca File write failed");
  }
  tempCA.close();

  if (tempCert.print(AWS_CERT))
  {
    Serial.println("cert File was written");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("cert File write failed");
  }
  tempCert.close();

  if (tempKey.print(AWS_PRIVATE_KEY))
  {
    Serial.println("key File was written");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("key File write failed");
  }
  tempKey.close();

  File ca = SPIFFS.open("/ca.crt", "r");
  if (!ca)
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to open ca file for reading");
    return false;
  }

  File cert = SPIFFS.open("/cert.crt", "r");
  if (!cert)
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to open cert file for reading");
    return false;
  }

  File pk = SPIFFS.open("/cert.priv", "r");
  if (!pk)
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to open pk file for reading");
    return false;
  }
  if (net.loadCACert(ca))
  {
    Serial.println("Successfully loaded ca");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Could not load ca");
    return false;
  }
  if (net.loadCertificate(cert))
  {
    Serial.println("Successfully loaded cert");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Could not load cert");
    return false;
  }
  if (net.loadPrivateKey(pk))
  {
    Serial.println("Successfully loaded pk");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Could not load pk");
    return false;
  }

  net.setTimeout(20000);
  if (!net.connect(AWS_IOT_ENDPOINT, 8443))
  {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    char err_buf[1024];
    Serial.println(net.getLastSSLError(err_buf, 1024));
    Serial.printf("ssl_error: %s\n", err_buf);
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Connected to AWS!");
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, please avoid posting screenshots with compiler output. Instead, please copy the output text and paste it into your post (with relevant formatting).

You appear to be using an older version of the [WiFiClientSecure library](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/WiFiClientSecure) which has a different interface - `setCACert()` expects two arguments, the key and its length. Why don't you try that?

```
net.setCACert((const uint8_t*)AWS_CERT_CA, sizeof(AWS_CERT_CA) - 1);
```

The `- 1` strips the terminating null, as the function appears to take binary blob and those don't usually come with terminators. If authentication doesn't work, try removing that subtraction.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. I tried to upgrade the library, but with no luck so far. After replacing my local files by the files linked by you, it tried to include some mbedtls header files. I tried to install mbedtls library then, but got the following error message: "Platform entropy sources only work on Unix and Windows, see MBEDTLS_NO_PLATFORM_ENTROPY in config.h"

Your suggestion does not work though, as the first parameter still has the wrong type. Can you maybe explain why the first parameter must be an int? This does not make sense to me

Comment: The PlatformIO framework, which you're using, probably has a set of intertwined depending libraries where you can't easily upgrade one without upgrading the lot. And I'm not really sure what they've decided to use there. Maybe my link isn't correct.

Anyway, there's something strange - you say you're building for ESP32 but the PlatformIO framework is for ESP8266. They're not compatible, so which one is it?

As for argument type, your compiler output clearly states setCACert wants 2 arguments - a pointer to 8-bit byte array and an integer with its length. Feel free to cast to needed type.

Comment: Updated my answer to include the type cast.

Comment: Sorry but this still does not work as you are converting an char[] into uint8_t*. I saw that there´s another method loadCaCert which accepts a stream and the size of it. How can I create a stream out of my certificate files? I tried that, but it´s really hard for a C++ newbie

Comment: Now I am able to compile it. I will test and if it works, provide the solution. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: A pointer of type uint8_t* is often used in C as a starting address of an array of unsigned 8-bit integers. Since char[] is an array of signed 8-bit integers, you can cast between the two relatively easily.